# Why is my mongodb query not giving me the expected result?

Tags: mongodb, mgo

I'm using mongo to store the data in the database with go. So there are two collections named section and fields. section collection contains a document like:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Message", "status" : 1 }
```

and fields collection contains documents like below:-

```
{
    "_id" : 6,
    "lead_section_id" : 2,
    "help_text" : "This is a tool tip",
    "name" : "Test11",
    "status" : 9
}
{
    "_id" : 7,
    "lead_section_id" : 2,
    "help_text" : "This is a tool tip",
    "name" : "Test11",
    "status" : 1
}
```

see the field collection documents containing `lead_section_id is 2` while I'm fetching the records using `$lookup` aggregation then It will return both the documents in the field collection while I'm passing the status is equal to 0,1 in the query So in result why will resulting me like below

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Message",
    "slug": "Name",
    "status": 1,
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "lead_section_id": 2,
            "field_type": "text",
            "help_text": "This is a tool tip",
            "name": "Test11",
            "placeholder": "Enter the name",
            "slug": "test11111111",
            "status": 9
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "lead_section_id": 2,
            "field_type": "text",
            "help_text": "This is a tool tip",
            "name": "Test11",
            "placeholder": "Enter the name",
            "slug": "test11asdasd111111",
            "status": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Query in golang like

```
var queryIn []bson.M
queryIn = append(queryIn, bson.M{"_id": 2})
queryIn = append(queryIn, bson.M{"fields.status": bson.M{operator: []int{1,0}}})
// database connection
getCollection := sessionCopy.DB("Database").C("lead_section")
pipe := getCollection.Pipe([]bson.M{
    bson.M{
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "localField":   "_id",
            "from":         "lead_field",
            "foreignField": "lead_section_id",
            "as":           "fields"}},
    bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"$and": queryIn}},
})

err = pipe.One(&data)
fmt.Println(data, err)
```

How I will correct that query any suggestion, please.

Answer (score 0):

Well with that lookup you get both subdocuments into your document and there is at least one matching your status, so its a match. So if you want to exclude the subdocument/field with wrong status you need to unwind it and group again or you project and filter your fields array.

Comment: can you give me a mongodb shell example of it